# Discrepency in object size in Jprofiler/Jvisualvm

Tags: java, memory-management, jprofiler, jvisualvm

I am analyzing the heap report in jprofiler. I see two tabs i.e Classes and Biggest Object
Under class tab it display size  as 144B and Instance count as 1 of class com.test.Customer but under Biggest objects it size comes
out to be 35 MB. Why this is the discrepancy ? I though under class tab it displays summation of size of all
objects under classes tab. So in this case there is only one object of com.test.Customer so size under
classes and instance should have been equal. what i am missing here ?

similar behavior i found under jvisualvm

Comment: Probably "object graph size" vs. "instance size" in isolation.

Comment: I did google but did not find what object graph size means ?

Comment: Often called the "retained size". https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/sizes.jsp

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you got it. under classes tab , it dispays object shallow size and under Biggest objects it displays retained size. You can post it as answer so that it helps other too

Comment: See this post https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/heapdump-is-a-lie/